# Disabling form elements using an onChange event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, listbox

I'm trying to disable and enable form elements using a JavaScript function. The function is called when certain combo box values are selected. My code is able to enter the functions that disable and enable the elements, but the elements never change state. I've tested my code on another test page and it works successfully.

Here's some of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EnableMonsterFields(value)
    {
        if(value == "Monster Card")
        {
            document.getElementById("monsterCardType").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("level").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("monsterClassification").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("monsterAttribute").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("rank").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("qATK").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("qDEF").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("ATK").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("DEF").disabled = false;
        }
    }

    function DisableMonsterFields(value)
    {
        if(value != "Monster Card")
        {
            document.getElementById("monsterCardType").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("level").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("monsterClassification").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("monsterAttribute").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("rank").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("qATK").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("qDEF").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("ATK").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("DEF").disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my onChange call:

```
         <tr>
            <td>Card Type</td>
            <td><select name="cardType" id ="cardType" onChange="EnableMonsterFields(this.value); DisableMonsterFields(this.value)">
                    <option selected value ="Choose One">Choose One</option>
                    <?php 
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet))
                            {
                            echo ("<option value='" .$row['cardType'] ."'>" . $row['cardType'] . "</option>");  
                            }
                     ?>
                </select>
             </td>
        </tr>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Open the console and see if there are any errors

Comment: How would I open the console?

Comment: It depends on the browser. Google it

Comment: ok I found an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null was using google chrome

Comment: Now find the line of code it references, and that element is null, so find out why!

Comment: any idea on what this might mean? EDIT thanks

Comment: Sure thing, hit up the javascript chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript if you have more questions